# Integrating Azure Resource Health and Metrics into Grafana - Seeking KQL Snippets and tips maybe

Tags: azure, grafana, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-resource-graph

I am currently working on a project where I aim to integrate various Azure resource health, availability, and other critical metrics into Grafana for a monitoring dashboard.

- I need to query Azure Resource Graph for health and availability statuses of various Azure resources, like VMs, databases, etc. However, I'm struggling to find the correct paths and resource types (e.g., *'microsoft.resourcehealth/availabilitystatuses'* or *'microsoft.insights/components'*) to query this data. An example of a problematic query might be helpful here.
- I also want to include performance metrics (like CPU usage, memory utilization) in my dashboard. While I understand these are typically accessed via Azure Monitor, I'm unsure how to properly structure these queries in KQL and integrate them into Grafana.
- I tried to follow the MS-DOCS, but unfortunately I'm running into BadRequest, always.

Could anyone provide sample KQL snippets or guidance on querying Azure Resource Graph for resource health and availability statuses?

I tried to write the KQL-s myself, but I run into BadRequest errors also.